# How SendSync deals with thread pool

Tags: vb.net, sendmail, smtpclient

**Question1:**

I'm sending message using SendAsync:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendasync?view=netframework-4.7.2

I'm sending massive emails and I'm getting too much delay in the message callback: client.SendCompleted

The email is sent async but the callback appear to be serial, it appears there is only one thread sending and receiveing the emails.

e.g. If a message callback delays 1 second to be back from the mail servers, and I send 20 emails it will delay about 20 seconds to all messages to be delivered and completed.

So it appears there's just one thread sending the messages in a sequencial queue...

If SendAsync internally deals with thread pool is there a way to change the number of threads in this pool, max num threads an other things related to thread pools?

**Question2:**

Another related question about SendMailAsync:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.2

Internally, SendMailAsync does the same thing of SendAsync, despite the fact the code design is a little different?

What's the real difference between SendAsync to SendMailAsync; should it solve the problem I'm relating in the quesiton 1?

**THE CODE**

```
Dim counter = 0

Public Async Function SendEmail(email As String, bodystuff As String) As Task
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient() '"email-smtp.us-west-3.amazonaws.com")
    Dim hostloginpass = "email-smtp.us-west-3.amazonaws.com, AKDKJDAKJ2SKJMSDKJ2,AK2KD298;kdj2kjdkjaiuwkmp2KKK2098K2la97ksjNW,Test_Site"
    smtp.Host = cla_util.sGetToken(hostloginpass, 1, ",")
    smtp.Port = 587
    smtp.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(getTokenFromArr(hostloginpass, 2, ","), getTokenFromArr(hostloginpass, 3, ","))
    smtp.EnableSsl = true

    Dim from As New MailAddress("contact@myserver.com", "Info", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
    Dim [to] As New MailAddress(email)
    Dim message As New MailMessage(from, [to])
    message.Body = String.Format("The message I want to send is to this <b>contact: {0}{1}</b>", vbCrLf, bodystuff)
    message.IsBodyHtml = True
    message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    message.Subject = "Test email subject"
    message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8


    'commented -> Await smtp.SendMailAsync(message)
    smtp.SendMailAsync(message)

    counter = counter + 1

    System.Console.WriteLine("Counter -> " & counter)
End Function

Dim _isCompleted
Dim _timing

Dim Tasks As New ArrayList

Public Async Sub StartEmailRun()
    Try
        Dim sWatch As New Stopwatch()

        sWatch.Start()

        For i = 0 To 50
            Tasks.Add(SendEmail("a_test_email@gmail.com", "email test"))
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("SETP OUT OF THE SENDING")

        _isCompleted = True

        sWatch.Stop()
        _timing = sWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Async Sub StartEmailRun2()
    Try
        Dim sWatch As New Stopwatch()

        sWatch.Start()

For i = 0 To 50
    Dim thread as New Thread(
      Sub() 
        SendEmail("a_test_email@gmail.com", "email test")
      End Sub
    )
    thread.Start()
Next

        Console.WriteLine("SETP OUT OF THE SENDING")

        _isCompleted = True

        sWatch.Stop()
        _timing = sWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: They use the same method under the hood, but the second returns a Task from a `TaskCompletionSource`. It's awaitable. The first uses a `SendOrPostCallback`. Consider it event-driven. It's different the way you can handle a pool of these objects. Using the `SendMailAsync` method, you can start a list of task, using the `SendAsync` method you can attach a handler to the `SendCompleted` event of you SmtpClient objects. Probably easier to  use if you're not familiar with pooling tasks.

Comment: _"So it appears there's just one thread sending the messages in a sequencial queue"_ - The process is an asynchronous operation so there is no specific thread involved. Perhaps the delay is caused by the UI thread having to handle all these callbacks? Are you sending messages from the `SendComplete` callback or are you using multiple `SmtpClient`s and sending all messages at once? Please include some code in your question so we can see what's actually going on.

Comment: @VisualVincent, you said there is no specific thread involved, but I can see the exit of many threads after sending emails.

Comment: @Jimi, If the SendAsync methods use their internal Pool of threads, what could cause the delay in the SendCompletedCallback? I think there is a limitation in somewhere, maybe there internal threadpool is set to have just one thread, because of this I see the sequencial behaviour

Comment: As already described, SendMailAsync sets a `TaskCompletionSource`, which is passed as the `Object` of the SendAsync method. It also sets a custom `SendCompleted` event, which handles the error/cancellation status and calls `[TaskCompletionSource].TrySetResults()`. It returns a Task. How you handle these Tasks (and the way you schedule them) it's up to you. You can run the Task as a threadpool-thread, await a single Task or `Task.WhenAll()` a list ot Tasks. Where the Task(s) is/are run in this case, is not of your concern and it's irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, @Jimi, I did that, there was a long delay. I'm talking about sending, about 50 emails at the same time. It appears there is something blocking the messages to be delivered at the same time, or at least to be responsed at the same time. I'm using SES and the deliveryDuration is in the maximum of 1 second. So If I sent 50 emails it would delay about in the maximum of 3 seconds to all emails to be answered. But it delays about 50 seconds, so it appers there is only one thread managing the email sending/delivering, even the email sending being async.

Comment: You're not showing any code and I have no idea what are the sendmail policies of the service you're using to deliver those messages. So, not much that I can add to what I've already said.

Comment: @Jimi the code is posted, it is very simple indeed. I did not use Task.WhenAll, just posted the emails... and saw when the last message sent was answered, it delayed about 50 seconds

Comment: _"I can see the exit of many threads after sending email"_ - Of course you can, because it does outsource its work to different threads on the system. What I said was that it doesn't utilize a _**specific**_ thread, i.e. it doesn't start just a single thread to handle all e-mails. It lets the system run each task on any available thread in the system threadpool.

Comment: @VisualVincent ok thanks, because of that I excpeted the process of receiving emails on the callback should be faster, once there are many threads being triggered simultaneously async "by the API". So it is very weird the process to deliver a lot to receive the callback of 50 emails simultaneously (see the code I posted).

Comment: Right now your main cause of delay is that you use `Await` as it will suspend execution until the e-mail has been sent. If you do not want to do this just use `SendAsync` instead.

Comment: The code is awaiting a single Task and you have a loop that sends one message at the time. If the mail service takes 1 second to carry out the request and return the result, then you need 50 seconds to complete all the Tasks. You could instead schedule a pool of Tasks, calibrated on the policies of your service (some don't allow to send mail in batch or limit the number of mail messages that can be processed).

Comment: For the record, if you want to send the _exact_ same e-mail to multiple addresses you can add more receivers to the [`MailMessage.Bcc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc?view=netframework-4.7.2) collection and you'd just need to call `SendAsync()` once.

Comment: @VisualVincent this was just an example to to the testes, the emails are sent to different addresses, and the message is different. So I couldn't use the bcc.

Comment: Noted. Then you should do as I suggested earlier and remove `Await` and just use `SendAsync()` instead. Like Jimi said the service might have limits to how many mails you can send or how often, so you might need to divide it into batches.

Comment: @Jimi I created the simple test: StartEmailRun2() (see the code above), I also removed the await in the smtp.SendMailAsync(message); AND created new threads to be sent on StartEmailRun2(). But the 50 messages sent still delays a lot, about 50 seconds to all to be sent. I think there is some limitation on SmtpClient, maybe there is a limitation somewhere...

Comment: This is another article with many threads sending emails: http://techzigg.com/2015/07/send-bulk-emails-using-multi-threading-in-net/ in my case it delays a lot to the messages to be delivered, in my case even if I create only 10 emails (10 threads) it delays about 10 seconds to deliver all messages. I know it's not good to create many threads, but just for example the creation of 10 threads it should dealy so much.

Comment: I have previously inspected the source code of the `SmtpClient` and I haven't found anything that indicates that there would be a limitation or bottleneck. Infact it should perform its work rather efficiently. There could however be a limitation on the SMTP server that you are using, your connection, or simply the protocol itself (SMTP isn't slow but it's also not fast).

Comment: Not that it should make _that_ big of a difference, but note that the threads do you no good as you're still calling `SendMailAsync()`, which, by design, already moves the sending of the e-mail to another thread. If you're going to utilize raw threads yourself you should only call `Send()`, otherwise call `SendAsync()` or `SendMailAsync()` (the latter only when you need to `Await`).

Comment: For me sending 8 e-mails to different addresses using your code is pretty much instant. I would start by looking for limitations on the SMTP server's side.

Comment: @VisualVincent, the SmtpClient is obsolete, I saw in documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @VisualVincent, I did the same program in java and worked well, so it is not the server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55738290/is-vb-net-smtpclient-api-limited-compared-to-java-sendmail?noredirect=1#comment98165521_55738290

Comment: Glad you found the cause!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I think is that SmtpClient is obsolete:

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2

"SmtpClient doesn't support many modern protocols. It is compat-only. It's great for one off emails from tools, but doesn't scale to modern requirements of the protocol."

"Use MailKit or other libraries."